# Google Cloud Datalab - Create your own Python environment

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

The default [Google Cloud Datalab](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstart) only comes with two default kernels: python2 and python3.

[image]

Is it possible to create our own extra virtual environment?

Many thanks,

Comment: By "extra virtual environment" do you mean an extra kernel?

Comment: Yes. For example I want to force a specific version of python; or to install extra dependencies without affecting the global environments.

Comment: You can use the pip package `virtualenv` for that.

Comment: I mean I want to be able to select the virtualenv within the Notebook ... By default when I installed Cloud Datalab, there are only 2 choices as shown in my post. I want to be able to add my own virtualenv ...

Comment: I see. That dropdown is meant to surface the installed kernels in the Datalab image, not the virtual environments within a specific kernel. You can fork the open source repository and make your own changes of course, but I'd venture to say that's a decent amount of work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could modify Datalab docker image and put it into GCE: https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/wiki/Getting-Started#using-your-modified-datalab-image-on-gce or run it locally: https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/wiki/Getting-Started#using-datalab-locally

Comment: Thanks rtbf, so modifying the image is the only way? I was trying to avoid this path  and hope that there is a configuration somewhere that I can just modify ...

Comment: As commented by rtbf and yelsayed, the only option is to modify Cloud Datalab's worker image. But you can also consider to create a feature request on [Cloud Datalab's tracker](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=187138&template=1162737).