# GCP and Datalab with Python 3.6, Need to use Jupyter on GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-datalab, fast-ai

I'm trying to use fastai's libraries, but some of the data accessing tools built in to those libraries are dependent on HTML objects. For example, the DataBunch.show_batch attribute produces an HTML object that is easiest to use in Jupyter. I need to run my testing on GCP (or another cloud), and here are the issues:

- fastai has some libraries that are dependent on Python3.6 or greater ([new string format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53517455/i-get-the-error-while-importing-the-fastai-library-after-install))
- GCP doesn't have a good way to interface with Jupyter NBs. I had it set up with some trouble, but then my computer needed reformat, and now I am questioning if I should set up again. The previous method was largely based on [this.](https://towardsdatascience.com/running-jupyter-notebook-in-google-cloud-platform-in-15-min-61e16da34d52)
- GCP apparently has something meant to provide an interface between it and Jupyter NBs, called Datalab. However, Datalab does not support Py3.6 or greater, [per this link.](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/1990)

I see a few options:

1. Develop my own data visualization techniques by subclassing fastai's libraries and skip Jupyter altogether
2. Create a Jupyter-to-GCP interface in a different way, basically redoing the steps in link in the second bullet point above.
3. Use one of the containers ([docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51454150/google-cloud-datalab-create-your-own-python-environment)) that I keep hearing about on Datalab that allow me to use my own version of Python

Does anyone have other options for how I can make this connection? If not, can anyone provide other links for how to accomplish 1, 2, or 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow [this guide](https://course.fast.ai/start_gcp.html) from fast.ai to create a VM with all the required libraries pre-installed. Then, following the same guide you can access JupyterLab or Jupyter Notebooks in this VM. It's simple, fast and comes with Python 3.7.3.

Comment: Thanks, actually fixed my issues with Jupyter (I had a 403 error that I had to modify the .jupyter files on GCP host) but I agree, this is probably the best how-to on the subject. I also found this site: [https://ljvmiranda921.github.io/notebook/2018/01/31/running-a-jupyter-notebook/]  while I was searching, it's very fundamental, not specific to GCP so it is helpful for a general understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a notebook using GCP's [AI Platform Notebooks](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-notebooks/).

It should give you a one-click way to create a VM with all the libraries you need preinstalled.  It'll even give you a URL that you can use to directly access your notebook.

Comment: This is a misleading response. GCP's AI Platform comes with Python 3.5 and the OP was very clear that he needed Python 3.6.